# Atualização do Android Studio: preview adicionando sombra no XML

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

Desde a última atualização ao Android Studio 3.3, apareceu uma sombra em cada um dos meus elementos no layout de visualização do XML. Apesar de não aparecer na renderização compilada, atrapalha de mais na edição.

Como faço para removê-los? ou será que isso é um BUG? está muito chato

Não é na codificação, pois está assim em todas as views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="14dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearMain"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_notificacao_drawable"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDia"
                style="@style/titulosGrande"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="09"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMes"
                style="@style/titulosGrande"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Set"
                android:textColor="@color/fonte_cinza"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearMain"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearMain"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitulo"
                style="@style/titulosPequenos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Titulo da notificação"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescricao"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/textoNormal"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Pet Shop Ciade Nova está com uma promoção de banhos toda quarta-feira!"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/fonte_cinza"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearTextoAdicional"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAdicional"
                style="@style/textoNormal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_chip_drawable"
                android:text="Eu quero!"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/divisor_mono" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não uso Android Studio por isso não vou falar asneira, mas veja esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211300/android-studio-disable-shadow-around-textview-in-layout-editor-in-version-3-3/54211447#54211447) no SOEN

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas como ele mesmo disse que nao encontrou nenhuma maneira de desativar (apenas na nova versao beta), isso apareceu dps da atualizacao da 3.3
Atrapalha de mais na edição dos elementos por causa da sombra em tempo de edição

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso é um bug: [LinearLayout Rendering issues in Android Studio 3.3](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122829431).

O problema foi resolvido, e estará disponível no próximo [*release*](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122829431#comment7):

> For the shadow in LinearLayout, actually we use it to indicate the
>   direction of LinearLayout. But we agree it is quite annoying for
>   seeing a clear preview.
>
> So we remove that shadow when LinearLayout is not selected. It would
>   be release in the following version.